Sway WM stopped working
I've recently had Sway WM stop working on my Lenovo ThinkPad T490 with Debian 12 Bookworm.
I suspect the issue was my having done an
apt upgrade
which may have moved some low-level packages causing the break.
Previously, sway would work just fine - I'd log into my account with command line, type in
sway
and the window manager would start up. Now when I type
sway
in I get
[wlr] [backend/backend.c:217] Found 0 GPUs, cannot create backed
[wlr] [backend/backend.c:386] Failed to open  any DRM device
[sway/server.c:56] Unable to create backend

I've tried
sudo apt remove sway
sudo apt install sway

but the problem persists.
Any ideas on how to fix this and get Sway working again?
